# Get coordinates from API request before showing on Maps

Tags: java, android, rest, google-maps

I developed an app in which i am receiving latitude and longitude through API REST from my server, so what i want is that the api call will be solved before the display of such coordinates on map. Please guide me how to do this.

I've already implemented a solution but it seems to not work.

From the stack trace I've got this message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: pro.rane.myapplication, PID: 1590
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                  at pro.rane.myapplication.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:160)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bw.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1805)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

I am conscious that this error is caused by the fact that function getCoordinates() doesn't work properly. I've also tried in past to use Volley library but it didn't work in same way. How can I make my API request works ?

Please note that the url is working, if you do your own get request on my server you can see the correct result in your browser.

Here's my code:

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";

private GoogleMap mMap;
private String info;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null)
        info = b.getString("qrCodeInformation");
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

/*connection to obtain the array  of positions*/


private static String[][] getCoordinates(String tran_id) throws JSONException {

    String dummy_tran_id = "1";

    String richiesta = "http://myurl/getArticleTravel?tran_id=" + dummy_tran_id;

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(richiesta);

    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Errore http request",""+e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception squish) {
            Log.i(squish.getMessage(), squish.getMessage());
        }
    }

    JSONArray jObject;
    String[][] coordinates;

    jObject = new JSONArray(result);
    String[] latitude = new String[jObject.length()];
    String[] longitude = new String[jObject.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++) {

        latitude[i] = jObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(LATITUDE);
        longitude[i] = jObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(LONGITUDE);
    }

    coordinates = new String[latitude.length][longitude.length];

        for(int i =0; i < latitude.length;i++){
            coordinates[i][0] = latitude[i];
            coordinates[i][1] = longitude[i];
        }


    //String[][] dummy_coordinates = {{"45.465454", "9.186515999999983"}, {"41.9027835", "12.496365500000024"}};

    return coordinates;
    //return dummy_coordinates;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    String[][] coordinates  = {{"45.465454", "9.186515999999983"}, {"41.9027835", "12.496365500000024"},{"40.9027835", "15.496365500000024"}}; //= null;
    try {
        coordinates = getCoordinates(info);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Integer a;
    mMap = googleMap;
    View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);
    TextView numTxt = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);

    for (a = 0; a < coordinates.length; a++) {

        if(a==0){
            numTxt.setText("Go");
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(coordinates[a][0]), Double.parseDouble(coordinates[a][1])))
                    .title("GO")
                    .snippet("Start point "+ a.toString())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(this, marker)))
            );
        }else {
            numTxt.setText(a.toString());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(coordinates[a][0]), Double.parseDouble(coordinates[a][1])))
                    .title(a.toString())
                    .snippet("Arrival point " + a.toString())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(this, marker)))
            );
        }
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(coordinates[a][0]), Double.parseDouble(coordinates[a][1])),5));
    }



}
// Convert a view to bitmap
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.disconnect();
}
}
```

Comment: You should put `getCoordinates` in an `AsyncTask` then, in `onPostExecute` either return the value to the `Activity` through an interface method or perform actions on a passed in map reference.

Comment: could you please post a link with and example of these functions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the AsyncTask class and use `doInBackground` to handle the work from `getCoordinates` in a background thread.

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, YourReturnType> {

     public interface OnFinishListener{
         void onFinish(YourReturnType result);
     }

     private OnFinishListener mListener;

     public OnFinishListener setOnFinishListener(@Nullable OnFinishListener l){
         mListener = l;
     }

     @Override
     protected YourReturnType doInBackground(Void... params) {
         // Replace all "YourReturnType" with the actual type/object you want to return
         YourReturnType returnValue; 

         // Do your work here and build/create your returnValue

         return returnValue;
     }

     // This will get called automatically after doInBackground finishes
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(YourReturnType result) {
         // If listener is set
         if(mListener != null){
             mListener.onFinish(result); // Return the returnValue
         }
     }
 }
```

In your `Activity` when you want to get the coordinate values, execute your `AsyncTask` and set the listener interface;

```
YourAsyncTask yourTask = new YourAsyncTask();
yourTask.execute();
yourTask.setOnFinishListener(new YourAsyncTask.OnFinishListener(){
    @Override
    public void onFinish(YourReturnType result){
        // Retrieve your returned value from result
        // And if mMap is ready, perform map actions
    }
});
```

[AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your disponibility and for the really clear example!